# How can I get all combinations of a String with the given replacements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, math, permutation

I would like to return all possible combinations for a string while maintaining the proper order of everything and avoiding duplicates. The reason for this? I'd like to make answers for some Japanese quizzes more flexible by allowing a mix of kana and kanji. As such, I require all possible combinations for comparison against the user's answer.

This is the current syntax of the function: ([located here](https://github.com/SethClydesdale/genki-study-resources/blob/99a907842c59bd83f75e353b7bf75afaf559cfcb/resources/javascript/genki.js#L2167))

```js
Genki.getAlts('{月曜日}と{水曜日}と{金曜日}に{日本語}のクラスがあります', 'げつようび|すいようび|きんようび|にほんご');
```

The text within curly braces is the text that will be replaced by the alternative text in the second argument, I'll refer to these simply as **replacements**. HOWEVER, the alternate text should ONLY replace the same index. That is:

- 月曜日 can only be replaced with げつようび
- 水曜日 can only be replaced with すいようび
- and so on...

To give a simple example of what I'd like to achieve. Say I have the following:

```js
Genki.getAlts('...{A}...{B}...', '1|2', true);
```

I'd like it to return all combinations, such as below.

```js
'...1...{B}...'
'...1...2...'
'...{A}...2...'
'...{A}...{B}...'
```

The current implementation works well with 2-7 given replacements, but when given more than 8, the total combo coverage begins to drop. The total amount of combinations can be calculated using this formula: `Math.pow(2, 8)`, which would return "256" combinations for 8 replacements, but currently getAlts() is only returning 234 combos, which means we're missing 22, only giving us 91% combo coverage.

So that is where I'm currently stuck.  You can review the current code via the links below. (and yes, it's rather hackish) Being self-taught I tried my best to get as many combos as possible, but I'm afraid that my skill with mathematics isn't that good. I'm sure there's a much simpler way of going about this and I'm just overthinking it.

- **code:** [Genki.getAlts()](https://github.com/SethClydesdale/genki-study-resources/blob/99a907842c59bd83f75e353b7bf75afaf559cfcb/resources/javascript/genki.js#L2167)
- **test page:** [lesson-4/workbook-6](https://sethclydesdale.github.io/genki-study-resources/lessons/lesson-4/workbook-6/?debug) || [page source](https://github.com/SethClydesdale/genki-study-resources/blob/master/lessons/lesson-4/workbook-6/index.html#L99) (the console will show all current combinations)

As an example of the current algorithm's failure, open your console, and you should see a warning for the last problem, saying something along the lines of:

> 234/256 (91.40625% combo coverage for 8 replacements; 22 missing combos

Code for this problem:

```js
Genki.getAlts('{1:私}はきのう{学校}で{1:写真}を{1:撮}りました。{2:私}は{家}でも{2:写真}を{2:撮}りました。', 'わたし|がっこう|しゃしん|と|わたし|いえ|しゃしん|と', true);
```

and a much simpler one with 10 replacements for performing test cases in the console:

```js
Genki.getAlts('{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}', '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10', true)
```

Is there any possible and simplistic way of returning all the combinations for a string regardless of how many replacements are specified? While I do know how many combinations there are, using `Math.pow(2, n)`, I'm unsure of how to properly get them all.

I am open to hearing about existing algorithms or frameworks for achieving this.

PS: as things are, the algorithm works fine for 2-7 replacements, with very few problems ever reaching or going above this threshold. However, when they do, there's a chance that the user's answer will erroneously be marked wrong and I'd like to avoid this. The simplest solution would obviously be to avoid ever breaking 7, but that's not always possible, and furthermore, the current way I'm achieving this isn't optimal, so I would like to optimize it as well.

Comment: "As such, I require all possible combinations for comparison against the user's answer" - wouldnt it be easier, to check the string iteratively, and check replacements by themselves, and not actually construct all possibilities, which would potentially be very very many? E.g. construct a regex, and test it, or similar?

Comment: Why does the second to last snippet contain `{1:` and `{2:`? Are those numbers relevant to how the replacements should be performed or no? I didn't see anything like that in your other examples.

Comment: In the case of identical replacements, they're prefixed with a number to avoid replacing the wrong index.

Comment: The prefix shouldn't be necessary assuming the algorithm is implemented correctly... would it be okay to post a solution that expects no prefixes to exist?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes, that would be fine.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I had initially considered taking such a route, though the issue I had with that was identifying the replacement points within the user's answer.

Comment: To elaborate on the above, i'd just do something like `const constructRegex = (strings, ...keys) => new RegExp(keys.reduce((p, c, i) => p + \`(${c}|${kana(c)})\` + strings[i + 1], strings[0]), "u"); let passed = constructRegex\`${"月曜日"}と${"水曜日"}と${"金曜日"}に${"日本語"}のクラスがあります\`.test(userInput);`, mostly to be taken as pseudocode.

Comment: It would of course be even better, could you algorithmically detect kanji sequences, e.g. like [jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9C%88%E6%9B%9C%E6%97%A5%E3%81%A8%E6%B0%B4%E6%9B%9C%E6%97%A5%E3%81%A8%E9%87%91%E6%9B%9C%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AB%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99), but i guess it's pretty optional.

Comment: It's a neater way to go about it, that's for sure. I might try playing with it to see if I could make use of something like it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem using binary math. Here's an approach that generates the array of strings:

```js
function getAlts(str, alt) {
  var subs = alt.split('|');
  var length = subs.length;
  var permutations = Math.pow(2, length);
  var results = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < permutations; ++i) {
    var bitIndex = 0;
    var result = str.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/g, function (match, p1) {
      var subIndex = bitIndex++;
      var bit = length - 1 - subIndex;
      return ((1 << bit) & i) ? subs[subIndex] : p1;
    });

    results.push(result);
  }

  return results;
}

console.log(getAlts('...{A}...{B}...', '1|2'));
```

Or if you're able to use ES6 (ECMAScript 2015), you can write a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to use less memory:

```js
function* getAlts(str, alt) {
  var subs = alt.split('|');
  var length = subs.length;
  var permutations = Math.pow(2, length);

  for (var i = 0; i < permutations; ++i) {
    var bitIndex = 0;
    var result = str.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/g, function (match, p1) {
      var subIndex = bitIndex++;
      var bit = length - 1 - subIndex;
      return ((1 << bit) & i) ? subs[subIndex] : p1;
    });

    yield result;
  }
}

var results = getAlts('{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}', '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9');
var total = 0;

for (var result of results) {
  console.log(result);
  total++;
}

console.log('total:', total);
```

Comment: It works incredibly well, THANK YOU! All I can say is that you're like a Math (and JS) Magician, haha. I'm gonna immortalize your name in the code, because I would've been stuck on this forever without your help. Thanks again!!